# Building OpenSSL and LibCURL from sources (Ubuntu) with undefined references

Tags: c, linux, ssl, curl, build

I'm trying to port a .dll project from Windows to Linux and I need to build `OpenSSL` and `cURL` **STATICALLY**. For this, I've tried to compile `zlib` as well but I get some errors I can't figure out how to solve.

I didn't use `sudo` except for `zlib`'s `$ sudo make install` (since I installed it in default location `/usr/local/`). This is how I installed the 3 of them:

**zlib** (from $HOME/software/zlib-1.2.11)

- `$ ./configure --static`
- `$ make V=1`
- `$ make test` OK
- `$ sudo make install` installed in `/usr/local/lib` without errors

**openSSL1.1.0g** (from $HOME/software/openSSL1.1.0g)

- `$ LIBS="-lcrypto -lz -ldl" ./config -fPIC -static --debug zlib no-zlib-dynamic --prefix=$HOME/<project_path>/openssl/openssl_debug_64bit_static-linux enable-ssl2 enable-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method no-shared no-threads`
- `$ make V=1`
- `$ make test` OK
- `$ make install` installed where specified without errors

**curl** (from $HOME/software/curl-7.57.0)

- `$ LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -lz -ldl" ./configure --disable-shared --with-ssl=$HOME/<project_path>/openssl/openssl_debug_64bit_static-linux --enable-debug --prefix=$HOME/<project_path>/libcurl64-linux/debug/ --without-librtmp --without-ca-bundle --disable-ldap --disable-pthreads --disable-threaded-resolver --enable-static`
- `$ make V=1`
- `$ make test` they took a really long time to run and 4 of them failed, but I checked [test cases](https://curl.haxx.se/dev/keywords.html) and they were related to `TFTP` and `multiprotocol` (not relevant at first)
- `$ make install` installed where specified without errors

I'm still having issues like those:

```
../src/openssl/openssl_debug_64bit_static-linux/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_init':
/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g/crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:136: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g/crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:145: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
../src/openssl/openssl_debug_64bit_static-linux/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_finish':
/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g/crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:160: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g/crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:161: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
../src/openssl/openssl_debug_64bit_static-linux/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o): In function `zlib_stateful_compress_block':
/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g/crypto/comp/c_zlib.c:180: undefined reference to `deflate'
```

Things that I don't get:

1. Why the hell does it refer to where I built the source code from (`/home/jjimenez/software/openssl-1.1.0g`)? It's supposed to create a static library and put every symbol it needs inside the `.a`, isn't it?
2. If I execute this `nm -gC /usr/local/lib/libz.a | grep inflateInit_`, I get this output:

`00000000000005a0 T inflateInit_
                  U inflateInit_`

However, executing `nm -gC libcrypto.a | grep inflateInit_` (from inside where openSSL has been installed) I get:

```
                 U inflateInit_
```

From what I've [found](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), that `T` means the symbol is indeed there and it is in the `code` section. Why is it also present with `U` (symbol undefined)? Can't I asume it should be found when linking to this library? There's something definitely weird here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a start, install packages `libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `libssl-dev`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I've just installed `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. It looks like `libssl-dev` was already installed (`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.`)

Comment: Then you should be able to compile and link your own program.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I've done it again (just like mentioned in the question) and I get the same linking errors :S

Comment: Please clarify which is the first error message you got when building your own application (Which you couldn't solve.)

Comment: They are ordered although there are multiple of each kind of errors listed, as I said.

Comment: Then just solve them one by one.

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond I'd love to. I mentioned those `_strdup` are fine since we didn't fix them yet, but I want to fix libraries' linking problems which I don't know how to fix. This is, I don't know why it tries to use the other path and it can't find those libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I ended up solving it thanks to a teammate.

Static linking did not work as I thought it would, so `zlib` symbols were not included in `libcrypto.a`. I simply had to add the former to the CMake compilation and linker runs fine regarding those errors.